# How to get a OntClass from a rdfs:label?

Tags: java, jena, ontology

I'm using Jena/SPARQL and can't get a class from a label.

I'm using an ontology where all classes have a different rdfs:label, and trying to get the URI or OntClass from my model by making a request on the label.

i made my code looks like this :

-------edit--------

@Joshua : I tried your piece of code and unfortunately I still don't get any results, here's my code I changed :

```
        String labelOfTheClassIWant = "Quantity";

        String queryString = 
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>" +
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>" +
            "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>" +
            "PREFIX dul: <"+RDF.getURI()+">" +

                "SELECT ?c" +
                "WHERE  { ?c rdfs:label '" + labelOfTheClassIWant + "' }";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        for ( ; results.hasNext() ; ){
            final QuerySolution solution = results.nextSolution();

            System.out.println( "the class I want to find :"+solution.get("c"));}
```

And here are the few lines from my Ontology requiered for my code above :

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="#Amount">
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Quantity</rdfs:label>
```

if your code's working, I really don't understand what's wrong with mine :/
i'll re-re-check my code to make sure there isn't any stupid mistake but I so far I don't think so.

Comment: Can you provide any of the OWL data that you're querying over?  The query as you've got it looks, OK, but there could be something strange in the data that we can't see here.  More immediately troubling, though, is that you're getting `o1` from the `QuerySolution rb` (i.e., `RDFNode j = rb.get("o1")`) when it looks like your variable name is `c` (i.e., `SELECT ?c WHERE { ...`).  What happens if you `rb.get("c")`?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor : yes sorry, i re-wrote a piece of code to show the problem exactly and make it more simple to understand, but in my program i didn't made this mistake

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly where the problem lies when we don't have the whole problem in front of us (we don't have the data), but here's a small ontology with two classes, each of which has a label:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://example.org/labelled-classes#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.org/labelled-classes"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/labelled-classes#B">
    <rdfs:label>Class B</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/labelled-classes#A">
    <rdfs:label>Class A</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

When I run this query

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?class where { 
  ?class rdfs:label "Class A"
}
```

against the data using Jena's command line ARQ, I get these results:

```
$ arq --data labelled-classes.owl --query classByLabel.sparql
-------------------------------------------
| class                                   |
===========================================
| <http://example.org/labelled-classes#A> |
-------------------------------------------
```

so the query looks OK.  Now the question is what do we do in Jena?  Here's some Java code that executes the same query on the same data:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class ClassByLabel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String rdfxmlContent = ""+
                "<rdf:RDF\n" +
                "    xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"\n" +
                "    xmlns:owl=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\"\n" +
                "    xmlns=\"http://example.org/labelled-classes#\"\n" +
                "    xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\"\n" +
                "    xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\">\n" +
                "  <owl:Ontology rdf:about=\"http://example.org/labelled-classes\"/>\n" +
                  "<owl:Class rdf:about=\"http://example.org/labelled-classes#B\">\n" +
                "    <rdfs:label>Class B</rdfs:label>\n" +
                "  </owl:Class>\n" +
                "  <owl:Class rdf:about=\"http://example.org/labelled-classes#A\">\n" +
                "    <rdfs:label>Class A</rdfs:label>\n" +
                "  </owl:Class>\n" +
                "</rdf:RDF>\n" +
                "";
        final String queryString = "" +
                "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "select ?class where {\n" +
                "  ?class rdfs:label \"Class A\"\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "";

        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read( new ByteArrayInputStream( rdfxmlContent.getBytes()), null, "RDF/XML" );

        final ResultSet results = QueryExecutionFactory.create( queryString, model ).execSelect();
        while ( results.hasNext() ) {
            final QuerySolution solution = results.nextSolution();
            System.out.println( "?class:\t"+solution.get( "class" ));
            System.out.println( "?o1:\t"+solution.get( "o1" ));
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
?class: http://example.org/labelled-classes#A
?o1:    null
```

There could be something strange with your data, but I expect that it's that you're retrieving `o1` instead of `c`.  Notice that retrieving a variable that isn't bound doesn't produce an error, but just returns `null`.